# Exclusive part of an AC motor

Tags: meaning

I am trying to write a quiz question.

Currently it states, "Which of the following is an exclusive part of an AC motor?"

I have the impression that the question is implying that an AC motor consists of one part and it is one of the following choices. Shouldn't it be, "Which of the following parts belongs exclusively to AC motors?”

I feel like the original question is unclear or even incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your feelings are correct. The latter formulation conveys the meaning your are intending, which is that one of the parts presented can belong to an AC motor and no other type of motor, it is *exclusive **to** AC motors*.

The phrase: "... an exclusive part of an AC motor" is vague but not ungrammatical. It does not describe the manner in which the part may be exclusive. Is it so expensive that only the obscenely wealthy can afford one? That would certainly make it an exclusive part of an AC motor, but I can also think of a number of other potential scenarios.

Comment: Thank you very much.